# Monitors for presentation without PC

Tags: monitors

Are there monitors, preferably wall-mounted, where one can upload files e.g. from an USB-stick for a presentation without connection to a PC or Laptop?

Comment: A TV would do this just fine (images/videos). Anything more complicated like a PDF/Powerpoint/Web will require a computer. You could use a Raspberry Pi which is a computer with the size of your hand so you're not limited with TV functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various media players [for ~US$35](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00TOAAHG4) and up that can play a presentation in a standard video format, e.g. MP4 or AVI, through a television, if the TV does not already have that capability. If the presentation is in another format, e.g. MS PowerPoint or LibreOffice Impress, you'd need a small PC, such as @CaldeiraG suggests.

Another option might be a [large tablet computer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0167OR4V0), with [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/android-viewer/) installed.